# How to use FluorineFx in .Net 2005 and Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am flex beginner.
I want to create project in Flex and VS.Net using FluorineFX.
How to create Both Project (Flex and .Net).
Please help me.

Comment: I know how to create project in VS. But i Don't know how to create fluorine project in Flex and VS? I want to connect VS Project into Flex Project using FluorineFX.

Comment: I don't understand.  FluorineFX is just a framework for you to use in a server side application... How do you want to connect a server side Framework to a front end language? it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are samples available on the FluorineFX site:  http://www.fluorinefx.com/download.html